# Is it correct if I dont make the system partition (100MB) for the Boot loader on windows 7 during format?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, bootloader

Is it correct if I don't make the system partition (100MB) for the boot loader that Windows 7 setup automatically creates when a hard disk is not preformatted?

Comment: Correct, it will automatically create the partition on a blank hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly "correct" but it is not necessary to have the WinRE (Recovery) partition on the drive. It is [**fairly easy**](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/20/hack-to-remove-100-mb-system-reserved-partition-when-installing-windows-7/) to avoid the partition but not worth the time and effort in my opinion.

Comment: thank you for your answer john.I was wondering if removing this partition would affect overall Windows 7 system functions.Based on your answer this will not affect something except maybe the system restores?

Comment: Not even system restores, only Windows Recovery. It will not effect your system in any other way.

Comment: I install a Windows 7 without this System Partition and I was wondering why I couldn´t Recover the system from the recovery CD.Thanks +1